# Extract records from a file - Haskell

Tags: haskell, extract, criteria

///Edit

I have a problem with haskell. If someone can help me, that would be great.

I'm inserting records into a file using the following code:

```
check ::  Int -> Int
check a
|a > 0 && a<=10 = a
|otherwise = error "oh. hmm.. enter a number from the given interval"


ame :: IO ()
ame = do
    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Do you want to add new records? "
    question <- getLine
    if question == "yes" then do
        putStrLn "Enter your records:"
        newRec <- getLine
        appendFile name ('\n':newRec)

        --new lines--
        putStrLn "enter a number between 0 and 10: "
        something <- getLine
        return (read something:: Int)
        let response = check something 
        putStrLn response
        appendFile name ('\n':something)

        putStrLn "enter something new again: "
        something2 <- getLine
        appendFile name ('\n':something2)
        putStrLn "a"
    else
        putStr "b"
```

Now I want to extract some records from this file, using a specific criteria. For example, i want to extract and display records  from even(or odd or any other criteria) rows. can I do that? if yes, how?

Also...
I want to check the user input. Let's say that I don't want him/her to enter a string instead of an integer. can I also check his/her input? do I need to create another function and call that function inside the code from above?

///Edit

thank you for answering. but how can i embed it into my previous code? 
I've tried now to create a function(you can see the above code) and then call that function in my IO. but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to display only certain rows.  If you want to base it off of the row number, the easiest way is to use `zip` and `filter`

```
type Record = String

onlyEven :: [Record] -> [Record]
onlyEven records =
    map snd $                -- Drop the numbers and return the remaining records
    filter (even . fst) $    -- Filter by where the number is even
    zip [1..]                -- All numbers
        records              -- Your records
```

This technique can be used in a lot of circumstances, you could even abstract it a bit to

```
filterByIdx :: Integral i => (i -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterByIdx condition xs = map snd $ filter (condition . fst) $ zip [1..] xs
-- Could also use 0-based of `zip [0..] xs`, up to you

onlyEven :: [a] -> [a]
onlyEven = filterByIdx even
```

---

If you want to check if an input is an `Int`, the easiest way is to use the `Text.Read.readMaybe` function:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

promptUntilInt :: IO Int
promptUntilInt = do
    putStr "Enter an integer: "
    response <- getLine
    case readMaybe response of
        Just x  -> return x
        Nothing -> do
            putStrLn "That wasn't an integer!"
            promptUntilInt
```

This should give you an idea of how to use the function.  Note that in some cases you'll have to specify the type signature manually as `case (readMaybe response :: Maybe Int) of ...`, but here it'll work fine because it can deduce the `Int` from `promptUntilInt`'s type signature.  If you get an error about how it couldn't figure out which instance for `Read a` to use, you need to manually specify the type.

---

You have

```
something <- getLine
return (read something:: Int)
let response = check something 
putStrLn response
```

To step through what you're trying to do with these lines:

```
something <- getLine
```

`getLine` has the type `IO String`, meaning it performs an `IO` action and returns a `String`.  You can extract that value in `do` notation as

```
something <- getLine
```

Just as you have above.  Now `something` is a `String` that has whatever value was entered on that line.  Next,

```
return (read something :: Int)
```

converts `something` to an `Int`, and then passes it to the *function* `return`.  Remember, `return` is not special in Haskell, it's just a function that wraps a pure value in a monad.  `return 1 :: Maybe Int === Just 1`, for example, or `return 1 :: [Int] === [1]`.  It has contextual meaning, but it is no different from the function `putStrLn`.  So that line just converts `something` to an `Int`, wraps it in the `IO` monad, then continues on to the next line without doing anything else:

```
let response = check something
```

This won't compile because `check` has the type `Int -> Int`, not `String -> String`.  It doesn't make any sense to say `"hello, world" > 0 && "hello, world" <= 10`, how do you compare a `String` and an `Int`?  Instead, you want to do

```
let response = check (read something)
```

But again, this is unsafe.  Throwing an error on an invalid read or when `read something` is greater than 10 will *crash* your program completely, Haskell does errors differently than most languages.  It's better to do something like

```
check :: Int -> Bool
check a = a > 0 && a <= 10

...

something <- getLine
case readMaybe something of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "You didn't enter a number!"
    Just a  -> do
        if check a
            then putStrLn "You entered a valid number!"
            else putStrLn "You didn't enter a valid number!"
putStrLn "This line executes next"
```

While this code is a bit more complex, it's also safe, it won't ever crash and it handles each case explicitly and appropriately.  By the way, the use of `error` is usually considered bad, there are limited capabilities for Haskell to catch errors thrown by this function, but errors can be represented by data structures like `Maybe` and `Either`, which give us pure alternatives to unsafe and unpredictable exceptions.

Finally,

```
putStrLn response
```

If it was able to compile, then `response` would have the type `Int`, since that's what `check` returns.  Then this line would have a type error because `putStrLn`, as the name might suggest, puts a string with a new line, it does not print `Int` values.  For that, you can use `print`, which is defined as `print x = putStrLn $ show x`

Since this is somewhat more complex, I would make a smaller function to handle it and looping until a valid value is given, something like

```
prompt :: Read a => String -> String -> IO a
prompt msg failMsg = do
    putStr msg
    input <- getLine
    case readMaybe input of
        Nothing -> do
            putStrLn failMsg
            prompt
        Just val -> return val
```

Then you can use it as

```
main = do
    -- other stuff here
    -- ...
    -- ...
    (anInt :: Int) <- prompt "Enter an integer: " "That wasn't an integer!"
    -- use `anInt` now
    if check anInt
        then putStrLn $ "Your number multiplied by 10 is " ++ show (anInt * 10)
        else putStrLn "The number must be between 1 and 10 inclusive"
```

You don't have to make it so generic, though.  You could easily just hard code the messages and the return type like I did before with `promptUntilInt`.

Comment: @Simplle Glad to hear it!